# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'

Tags: python, tornado

> RESTART:
>   C:\Users\alanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\FirstDayTornado.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\alanp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\FirstDayTornado.py",
>
> line 1,   in < module>
>       import tornado.ioloop ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'

this is the error message i receive I am currently trying to run tornado's 'hello world' example 
https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

I am currently up-to-date with my python idle being version 3.7.2

Comment: How do you install tornado  ? Did you 'pip install tornado' ?

Comment: Please format your code and describe the environment you're running in (i.e. any setup you've done). Likely, you either haven't installed tornado through pip, or haven't set up your PYTHONPATH properly

Answer (score 3):

Seems like tornado isn't installed. Install it using the following command.

> pip install tornado